# Timeout when fetching large amounts of data from MySQL?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to fetch an item from my queue, prioritizing items with girl names in them. I've ran into memory issues so started using chunk instead of `QueueItem::all()` but I'm still getting timeouts and the endpoint is taking at least 30 seconds to process if it doesn't time out before that.

Here is the controller

```
public function __invoke()
{
    $queueItem = null;

    QueueItem::chunk(1000, function ($queueItems) use ($queueItem) {
        foreach ($queueItems as $item) {
            if ($queueItem != null || QueueHelpers::hasGirlsName($item->item)) {
                $queueItem = $item;
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    if (! $queueItem instanceof QueueItem)
    {
        $queueItem = QueueItem::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
    }

    if ($queueItem == null) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $queueItem->delete();

    return new QueueResource($queueItem);
}
```

Here is the `QueueHelpers::hasGirlsName` method

```
public static function hasGirlsName($item): bool
{
    foreach (self::$girlNames as $name)
    {
        if (stripos($item, $name) !== false) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

My `$girlNames` have around 500+ items in them but no more than 2,000.

Comment: How many QueueItems are their? You could possibly push this into a job for a long running task.

Comment: 20,000 items likely to reach a million pretty soon.

Comment: I'd highly advise pushing this to a job, then using socket.io to signal that the job has finished to the font end.  its either that or dinking with php timeout on the script and on the web server

Comment: I'm sure this code can be optimized outside of a job to run much faster, which is essentially what I'm asking.